# How to retrieve contact picture using contact id

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want a function which takes in a contact id(long) and returns the corresponding contact pic(Bitmap or InputStream)
Have tried a lot. But I am not being able to pull it off.

PS - Min API Level = 10

Comment: what you have tried?Post your code..

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code:

```
private void setContactInfo(long id){
Bitmap photoBitmap = null;
Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);

Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    contact_text.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));//contact.text is a textView used to displays the contact name

    String id = getIntent().getData().getLastPathSegment();
    // Photo cursor

    String photoWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND "
            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
    String[] photoWhereParams = new String[] { id,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
    Cursor photoCur = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null,
            photoWhere, photoWhereParams, null);
    photoCur.moveToFirst();
    if (photoCur.moveToFirst() && photoCur != null) {

        byte[] photoBlob = photoCur.getBlob(photoCur
                .getColumnIndex(Photo.PHOTO));
        if (photoBlob != null) {
            photoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoBlob, 0,
                    photoBlob.length);

            contact_image.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap);//contact_image is an ImageView
        } else {
            photoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);//android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image is the default image if a Contact doesn't have any image stored
            contact_image.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap);
        }

    }
cursor.close;
photoCur.close;         

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I think I found a better way.

Comment: If you observe the code I posted is same as yours and I have also taken care of the condition where the contact picture is not available.

Comment: Yes, it gives a default pic, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but I was little surprised to know that you Found the solution just 1 hour ago when in fact I gave it to you almost 11 hours ago :)

Comment: Actually I didn't try yours at all. I didn't even see it. I was trying on my own accord and I did find it.

Comment: @arun ur code working fine. But i have one doubt. How to get that picture path. I need to store that picture path in my database. Please help me.

Comment: contact_image.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap); here i can able to set this image. But i want this image path before setting this image

Answer (score 0):

In your activity you need the **url** to download the picture. Use the following methods(make sure this code must be in your that activity, where you want to download the picture):

```
private class DownloadProfilePicture extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {



                    InputStream in = null;
                    int response = -1;

                    URL url = "your image url";
                    URLConnection conn = null;
                    HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;

                    conn = url.openConnection();

                    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

                    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpConn.connect();

                    response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                    if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                    }

                    if (in != null && in.available() > 807) {
                        yourBitmaptype.setBitmap(
                                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in));

                    } else {
                        users.get(screenName).setBitmap(
                                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                        R.drawable.default_profile_pic));

                    }
                    in.close();
                    in = null;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                users.get(temp).setBitmap(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                R.drawable.default_profile_pic));
                Log.e(TAG, "Downloading Image Exception.. Using default");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            // use post execute logic
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        // use pre execute logic
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }
```

and call it from `onCreate()` as `new DownloadProfilePicture().execute();`

Comment: Thanks! I think I found a better way.

Comment: How to get last inserted contact id. Please give me the code for that

Answer (score 0):

```
private ByteArrayInputStream getPhoto()
{

    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);     
    Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);     
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);     
    if (cursor == null) {         
        return null;     
    }     
    try 
    {         
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {             
            byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);             
            if (data != null) 
            {                 
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);             
            }         
        }     
    } 
    finally 
    {        
        cursor.close();     
    }     
    return null;

}
```

This is my code. It is working.